# Change of variables in $\int_{\Omega}(x+y+z)^2xyz \: dxdydz$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, riemann-integration

I have the triple integral $\int_{\Omega}(x+y+z)^2xyz \: dxdydz$ , with $\Omega=\lbrace (x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3:0\leq x+y+z\leq 1 , \:1\geq x\geq0, \: \: 1\geq y\geq 0,  \: \:1\geq z\geq 0 \rbrace$. I set

$\begin{cases}x=u\\y=v\\
z=w(1-u-v)\end{cases}$ but  the resut  isn't correct.

The  result must be $1/960$.

Comment: There is nothing bad with doing a change of variable, unless you are doing something wrong. How can we know why your result is not correct?

Comment: I hope that the book's result is correct! XD

Comment: OK I deleted my answer. The answer is 1/960 as I said and the integral can be directly integrated. You did not even mention how you get the wrong answer and it's impossible for me to point out which part you did was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Put
\begin{align*}
u &= z & v &= y+z & w &=x+y+z
\end{align*}
Then $\Omega$ is described by
\begin{align*}
0\leq u\leq 1 && u\leq v\leq 1 && v\leq w\leq 1
\end{align*}
Moreover, we have
$$
\frac{\partial(u,v,z)}{\partial(x,y,z)}=
\det
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
= -1
$$
This gives
\begin{align*}
\iiint_\Omega (x+y+z)^2xyz\,dV
&= \int_0^1\int_u^1\int_v^1 w^2(w-v)(v-u)u\left\lvert\frac{\partial(x,y,z)}{\partial(u,v,w)}\right\rvert\,dw\,dv\,du \\
&= \int_0^1\int_u^1\int_v^1 w^2(w-v)(v-u)u\,dw\,dv\,du \\
&\vdots \\
&=\frac{1}{960}
\end{align*}

Comment: Good :) But with my change of variables?